# R - dplyr - ifelse and filter

Tags: r, filter, widget, shiny, dplyr

I am building a widget on Shiny, and I would like to have the option "all" to select all of the data available, and don't perform a filtering.

Basically, I would like to have the following code (using dplyr):

```
filt<-sample(c("All", unique(mtcars$carb)),1)

data1<- mtcars %>% 
                  ifelse (filt=="All", select(), filter(carb==filt))
```

It will filter *mtcars* based on the value of *filt*.

If *filt=="All"* then it does not filter and return simply *mtcars*.

Any elegant solution?

Comment: How about `if (filt == 'All') {data1 <- mtcars} else {data1 <- filter(mtcars, carb == filt)}`?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it - but how to embed it within the Reactive Function in Shiny? I tried the following solution but it does not work:              `if (filt == 'All') {data1 <- reactive({mtcars }) } else {`                                          `data1 <-reactive({filter(mtcars, carb == filt) })} `

Comment: Add `data` at the end of the reactive. It will return that data frame.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work (with proper modifications to use the input value in this reactive for the `filt` variable):

```
reactiveObject <- reactive({
  filt <- sample(c("All", unique(mtcars$carb)),1)

  if (filt == 'All') {
    data1 <- mtcars
  } else {
    data1 <- filter(mtcars, carb == filt)
  }
  data1
})
```

Comment: Working great ! Thanks a lot Gopola.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try. If `folt="All"` then there is no filter, otherwhise just the Cars with `carb==filt` is returned.

```
   filt <-sample(c("All", unique(mtcars$carb)),1)
    filt
    if(filt=="All"){
      data1<- mtcars
    } else {
      data1<- filter(mtcars, mtcars$carb==filt)
    }
```

should do the trick