# dplyr filtering on all values in a Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am building a R Shiny where users can select a country and based on this a dataset will be filtered. The selection menu also contains an option "all", which in practise means that the particular filter will not be applied. I am seeking a solution where I can leave the code in my shinyserver section but ensure that it returns all values. Thus, when all is selected the case is in practise not applied.

When a country is selected the code looks as following:

```
  ShinySet %>% filter(CountryTo == "NL")
```

When no country is selected, I the code will look like one of the following:

```
  ShinySet %>% filter(CountryTo == "ALL")
  ShinySet %>% filter(CountryTo == "*")
```

The problem is that in both cases the filter will be applied, meaning that the output returns no rows, as none of the rows are within the selection.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to keep the structure of the statement intact but find a way that the particular filter is not applied.

Comment: Just to clear, You would like to show all the items when there is no filter selected instead of no items right?

Comment: When the variable is "ALL" then I would expect that no filters are applied thus that it would be the same as the original dataset.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use an `ifelse` condition before filtering?

Comment: That was one of my considerations but I will have more filters that can be applied and then it may get a complicated ifelse structure. I may have filters for country from, country to, shipment type, etc etc.

Comment: @amrrs: the solution you are suggestion is the following but I would prefer to have the one described above. Solution with ifelse statement:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978628/r-dplyr-ifelse-and-filter?rq=1