# dplyr filter variable set to filter nothing [r]

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, shiny, dplyr

Is there a value in that will make a dplyr filter not filter anything? I am using a variable to filter based on a drop down menu in Shiny.

I know there are answers with if statements like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978628/r-dplyr-ifelse-and-filter). However, I was curious if there was a way to do it by setting the filter value equal to something that means "do not filter anything."

Here is a reproducible example I am trying for.

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- structure(
  list(
    `Month Nm` = c("October", "August", "August",
                   "March", "January", "July"),
    Cycle = c(
      ">= 2nd Cycle Action",
      ">= 2nd Cycle Action",
      ">= 2nd Cycle Action",
      ">= 2nd Cycle Action",
      "ACK or RTA",
      ">= 2nd Cycle Action"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-6L),
  class = c("tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

filter_var <- October"

my_df %>% filter(`Month Nm` == filter_var) %>% View()

# How can I set the variable (filter_var) that will make the filter not filter anything?
filter_var <- "" # What can I set this to? 

my_df %>% filter(`Month Nm` == filter_var) %>% View() # I want the output to be everything
```

I have tried setting the value to NULL and TRUE and FALSE just for fun but no luck.

I suppose one way to do it is to find all distinct values in the column of interest and filter based on all that way? Is there a more succinct method?

Comment: This is just an example of my overall code. I have a user choose from a Shiny dropdown menu for a specific name, then that name becomes my variable to filter for. Then, elsewhere in my Shiny app, the output is updated based on the filter. Problem is, if the user does not choose a filter, or deletes the dropdown values completely, I still have the filter = filter_var in my code. Is there a way to set filter_var in such a way to actually NOT filter anything? Only way I can think of is to find all distinct values and set filter_var = all_distinct.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the "if" option because the code is actually much more complex than my example and I would have had lots of code embedded in my Shiny app.R file. I actually just figured out that I can capture Shiny Drop Down input and call functions in another script based on that input. I wasn't sure how to call functions from within a shiny output block. Turns out you can do that. I suppose I don't need the answer anymore. However, it still would be nice to know if this is possible without an "if" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not changing your dataframe to include implementation details if you can help it (and you can help it in this case).

You can use an or statement directly in the `filter` statement. Just add an option to your drop down menu named `"All Months"`, then change your `filter` statement:

```
my_df %>% filter(`Month Nm` == filter_var | filter_var == "All Months") %>% View()`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a dummy test value and use that in your filter condition as shown below -

```
dummy <- "all"

filter_var <- "all"

my_df %>%
  filter(`Month Nm` == filter_var | filter_var == dummy)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  `Month Nm` Cycle              
  <chr>      <chr>              
1 October    >= 2nd Cycle Action
2 August     >= 2nd Cycle Action
3 August     >= 2nd Cycle Action
4 March      >= 2nd Cycle Action
5 January    ACK or RTA         
6 July       >= 2nd Cycle Action

filter_var <- "August"

my_df %>%
  filter(`Month Nm` == filter_var | filter_var == dummy)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `Month Nm` Cycle              
  <chr>      <chr>              
1 August     >= 2nd Cycle Action
2 August     >= 2nd Cycle Action
```

`dummy` should be a value that doesn't already exist in your actual filter variable.